# Error en documento XSD: "s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'ficha' is invalid."

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema

No sé por qué el validador de esta página (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) me dice que tengo el documento XSD mal.

El error que me da concretamente es:

> Not valid. Error - Line 5, 58:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 58; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The
>   content of 'ficha' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid,
>   misplaced, or occurs too often.

El documento XSD es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="ficha">
        <xs:attribute name="numero" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
        <xs:element name="edad" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

El documento XML es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fichas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemalLocation="fichas.xsd">
  <ficha numero="1">
    <nombre>Ana Sanz Tin</nombre>
    <edad>22</edad>
  </ficha>
  <ficha numero="2">
    <nombre>Iker Rubio Mol</nombre>
    <edad>23</edad>
  </ficha>
</fichas>
```

Answer (score 1):

El documento .xml es valido, pero el .xsd es invalido.

El error:

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'ficha' is invalid.

Refiere estas leyendo el elemento "ficha", pero tienes que leer primeramente el elemento "fichas" para acceder a "ficha":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <fichas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemalLocation="fichas.xsd">
    <ficha numero="1">
    ...
    ...
```

Son varios detalles los que tienes en este archivo; ya que tienes una secuencia de elementos `<ficha>`, debes usar `<xs:sequence>`,
usa `type="xs:string"` en lugar de `type="xs:NMTOKEN"` para el `nombre`.

Este .xsd debe funcionar correctamente:

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="fichas">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ficha" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nombre"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="edad"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:decimal" name="numero" use="optional"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Te iba a dar votos pero no me deja, de todas maneras grcias de verdad.

Comment: Si la respuesta soluciono tu pregunta, puedes marcarla como correcta, realiza el [tour] del sitio.

Comment: @Carlos si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).